# Go back to start of the line in the REPL

Tags: console, julia, overwrite

Is it possible to include code in my script that will set the cursor back to the start of the current line as it prints output in the REPL? (i.e. so that what the user sees gets updated). I tried `\r` in `@printf` but it seems to do the same as `\n`.

So far the only solution I found is to `@printf` several `\b` characters:

```
julia> @printf("one\ntwo\rthree")
one
two
three
julia> @printf("one\ntwo\b\bhree")
one
three
julia>
```

Is there a better way to set the cursor to the beginning of the current line?  I am on a Windows system.

Answer (score 2):

You might have encountered a bug in the `@printf` macro. I just tried your example, and it now works fine -- i.e. it works as you expected it to work, the output `two` is now overwritten by `three`:

`julia> @printf "one\ntwo\rthree"
one
three`

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for you reply. Did you test on a Windows machine?  I tried it again, also with Julia version 0.4.6, and the '\r' still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

This works on a mac and linux.  Not sure though about windows.

```
for idx = 1:10
    sleep(1)
    @printf("\tSeconds Passed =%d%s", idx, '\r')
end
```

The `@printf` help says that it uses C style formatting, so this response was based on that.  The `\t` at the beginning is just to make the output a bit easier to see.

Comment: Thanks aireties for your help, but this does not work on Windows: it moves down a line as well...      @printf("Seconds Passed =%d%s", idx, "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b") does what I need, but feels a bit like a quick and dirty fix. I guess I'll just proceed using multiple \b's instead.